# Magic Leap App Simulator Issues with unity. Error : GLSL Compilation failed for shader Universal Render Pipeline unit

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, simulator

So, I have been trying to set up the Magic Leap App simulator for unity. I was following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqH0zv3e2AY
I got the GLSL shader error which i was not able to resolve.

I also got insufficient graphics support for app sim error while starting the simulator.
These are the specifications of my hardware :

```
Processor :  AMD Ryzen 9 6900HS with Radeon Graphics           3.30 GHz
Installed RAM : 16,0 GB (15,2 GB usable)
Device ID : 76AECB92-78C5-4BB0-A0B8-F9B5106793DB
Product ID : 00342-20859-10398-AAOEM
System type : 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch : No pen or touch input is available for this display
```